# Getting the next primary key without adding a new record is impossible, isn't it?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I considered the top google results, almost all functions of mysql and etc... Unfortunately, as far as I learned, **without adding a new row** into the table of a database, we can't know the next primary key. Please, say me I'm wrong. How can't there be any solution for this problem? I am disappointed.

Comment: You can't for certain (even reading the next value to be assigned by MySQL isn't guaranteed if you have multiple concurrent users); but the real question is "why should you need to?"

Comment: Because, in my project, I'm uploading pictures with AJAX, and beside it, then the article which contains the images is submitted . So I need to put a foreign key for the pictures so that they can related to candidate article. That is, I need to learn the primary key of the candidate article to be able to put this value as foreign key for images in the article.

Comment: Still doesn't require predicting the next id that will be assigned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Took about 7 seconds to find on Google:  https://www.bram.us/2008/07/30/mysql-get-next-auto_increment-value-fromfor-table/

```
SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT
FROM information_schema.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = "databaseName"
AND TABLE_NAME = "tableName"
```

Answer (score 2):

The *value* is present in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` (see [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/tables-table.html)).  Under reasonable assumptions, you can get the value there.

Reasonable assumptions:

- No changes to the system variables that affect auto increment.
- No concurrent transactions.
- No intervening reset of the value.

Answer (score 0):

with this request you have the last id in your table

SELECT MAX(id) FROM your_table

You can just add +1 to your request result.